# Show that $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^{*}$ s.t. $xy,yz,xz\in \mathbb{Q}$. If $x^3+y^3+z^3\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Q}$ .

My approach:

I notice that $x^2=\frac{xy\cdot xz}{yz}\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Also $y^2, z^2\in \mathbb{Q}$.
Then $(x+y+z)(x^3+y^3+z^3)\in\mathbb{Q},$ so $x+y+z\in\mathbb{Q}$ if $x^3+y^3+z^3\neq 0$.

In this case it's easy to show that $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Q}$.

What happen if $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$?

Comment: "What happen if $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$?" - then the statement is false: $x = 0$, $y = -\sqrt{2}$, $z = \sqrt{2}$. It would be great if you clarified what $\mathbb R^*$ is (I guess not https://mathworld.wolfram.com/R-Star.html)

Comment: @Dmitry To my knowledge it usually means non-zero real numbers, but yes, I don’t think it is universally standardized and it is best to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to use Fermat’s last theorem. I admit this is an overkill and there must be something more elementary.

If $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$, then two of them are of the same sign while the other is of the opposite sign. WLOG, assume $x,y>0$ and $z<0$. Write $w=-z$. Then,
$$x^3+y^3=w^3 \implies (x/w)^3+(y/w)^3=1^3.$$
However, $x/w=-\frac{xy}{yz}$ and $y/w=-\frac{xy}{xz}$ are positive rational numbers, so the equation is in contradiction with Fermat’s last theorem. Therefore, you are guaranteed that $x^3+y^3+z^3\neq0$.

Comment: $x,y,z$ need not be rational in $x^3+y^3=(-z)^3$. I don't see where we have integer solutions for FLT then.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I’ve added clarifications. Basically, even though $x,y,z$ are themselves not necessarily rational, their ratios are rational. Is it good now?

Comment: It's not the full FLT, just the $n=3$ case, which is elementary: proven by Euler in $1760$.

Comment: What you wrote is already proved here many times, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180026/242). Better to link to this in a comment then duplicate it further.

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't think this answer is duplicating it, but more applying it. I am applying that answer to show it is impossible that $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ in this question.

Comment: Your answer is a special case of  that linked, so it is a dupe. It should come as no surprise that this result already occurs here *many* times.

Comment: @BillDubuque But one still needs to (do some work, although easy, to) make the relation between that result and this question to give this answer? Otherwise this question is a dupe (until it says "no FLT" or "alternative solution") as it is easily answered by the post you linked? Also, I thought answering in the comments is discouraged? Apologies if I appear a little defensive. Question marks as I'm in doubt, not trying to interrogate.